# How to get Electrum 3.1.3 on bitcoin testnet?

Tags: client, electrum, testnet, sweep

I'm building an application on bitcoin and want to use testnet instead of using real bitcoins to do my test. I'm mainly using Electrum-3.1.3 to do sweeping of addresses. But how can I switch this to be on the testnet chain instead?

Comment: I would also like to know how to get Electrum mobile on testnet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General answer is running:
$ electrum --testnet

If you are using Mac OSX then open terminal an jump to:
/Aplications/Electrum/Contents/OSX
there you need to run:
& ./Electrum --testnet

On newer Mac OS versions 
`/Applications/Electrum.app/Contents/MacOS/run_electrum --testnet`

Comment: On my system dir is /Applications/Electrum.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: and `./run_electrum --testnet`

Answer (score 4):

If you install Electrum on Windows, you will have two programs you can start. One of them is called "Electrum Testnet".

Answer (score 3):

Run Electrum with the `--testnet` startup option.

Comment: testnet is not working for linux environment

Comment: and for linux? that doesnt exist